# Deactivate drag and drop for table in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to deactivate the drag and drop function for the table.
Can anyone tell me how we can do this?

```
return(
        <div 
            className="grid-container"
        >
            <table
                className="grid-table" 
                onMouseLeave={() => props.handle_mouse(false)}
                onMouseDown={() => props.handle_mouse(true)}
                onMouseUp={() => props.handle_mouse(false)}
            >
                <tbody>
                    {grid}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the disabled state of your drag n drop. and return nothing if the state says it's disabled.

```js
let isDisabled = false

// Logic to handle `isDisabled` state that would set it to true

return(
        <div 
            className="grid-container"
        >
            <table
                className="grid-table" 
                onMouseLeave={() => props.handle_mouse(false)}
                onMouseDown={() => isDisabled ? null : props.handle_mouse(true)}
                onMouseUp={() => props.handle_mouse(false)}
            >
                <tbody>
                    {grid}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> 
    )
```